# Python regex find match words by AND conditio

Tags: python, regex

```
    def count_conditions(input_str, listbox):
        electric_attributes = ['electric', 'batter', "power"]
        input_str = input_str.strip().replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n')
        pattern = re.compile(r'(\{AND.*?\})', re.DOTALL)
        matches = re.findall(pattern, input_str)
        
        line_num = 1

        for match in matches:
            attrs_found = []
            words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', match)
            for word in words:
                for attr in electric_attributes:
                    if attr in word.lower() and word not in attrs_found:
                        attrs_found.append(word)
                        
                        
            if attrs_found:
                message = "{} electrical attribute(s) found on lines {}-{} of AND condition: {}".format(
                    len(attrs_found), 
                    line_num, 
                    line_num + len(match.splitlines()) - 1, 
                    ', '.join(attrs_found)
                )
                
            else:
                message = "No electrical attribute(s) found on lines {}-{} of AND condition".format( 
                    line_num, 
                    line_num + len(match.splitlines()) - 1, 
                )
            listbox.insert("end", message)
            line_num += match.count('\n') + 1
```

I want the code to be able to determine the external "and" syntaxes, and not those that are already inside AND syntaxes.

For example lines 1-14 should be treated as 1 AND syntax, not 3.

```
{AND
condition_1:batterie
condition_2:samsung
{OR
{AND
condition_1:TV
condition_2:LCD
}
{AND
condition_1:remote
condition_2:TV
}
}
}

{AND
condition_1:batterie
condition_2:samsung
{OR
condition_3:TV
condition_4:remote
}
}
```

The **Output** should be:

```
1 electrical attribute found on lines: 1-14 of AND condition: batterie
1 electric attribute found on lines 15-22 of AND condition: batterie.
```

Please help! What am I doing wrong?
Or maybe other approach?

Comment: I'm not sure a regex is the simplest (or if it's even possible to use one) way to find the text enclosed is an outer "AND"; it seems to me counting open "{"s from the AND would be simpler.

Comment: This data seems like some kind of tree. Why don't you parse it as such, and then iterate through it?

Comment: Your example has the electrical attributes always at the top level of the tree. What if it is found at deeper levels? How does that influence the expected output?

Comment: No, it's not a tree, sorry, I am new to stackoverflow, now it's edited better.

Comment: what I am trying to achieve, is to check if an "AND" condition has an electric attribute or not.

Comment: @Swifty I'm not sure I understand what you mean by counting "{",  I also tried this pattern:
pattern = re.compile(r'(\{.*?\})', re.DOTALL)
But it's still not working the way it should.

Comment: What do you mean it is not a tree? Surely the first `{OR` is an operand for the first `{AND`, and so that `{OR` is a child of the `{AND` ... representing a tree. Now that you have removed lines from your sample input, I guess the `1-14` desired output is no longer consistent, making this question even more obscure.

Comment: {AND
condition_1:batterie
condition_2:samsung
{OR
{AND
condition_1:TV
condition_2:LCD
}
{AND
condition_1:remote
condition_2:TV
}
}
}
The AND syntax that contains the OR and AND conditions, have 14 lines, if you count also the closing "}"s.

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean with the "tree", sorry I was not familiar with parser tree of python. It does not matter where the electric attribute is find in the tree.

Comment: Do you mean with "it does not matter", that anyhow the result will be 1, 14 ?

Comment: What if more than one electrical attribute is found? How will that impact the output? What if it is found in an `OR` expression? This question really needs much more specification and examples.

Comment: I mean the electric attribute can sit wherever in the tree, no matter if it's at the top level or on deeper levels. If there are results it should be: 1 electric attribute between lines 1-14, if there aren't it should be: no electric attributes found between lines 1-14.

Comment: What if there are 2 matches between lines 1-14, and one is in a deeper `OR`? How will that affect the output?

Comment: If more electrical attributes it will be find in the parent the output should be: x electric attributes has been found in AND condition between lines 1-14. {AND{OR condition_1:batterie}} this would output 1 electric attributes found between lines 1-5

Comment: What if there are 2 matches between lines 1-14, and one is in a deeper OR? How will that affect the output? - 3 electric attributes were found in AND condition between lines 1-14

Comment: In your question the output has ": batterie" at the end. How will that be replaced when there are multiple matches?

Comment: @trincot: your last question is actually addressed in the original code

Comment: @Swifty, Sure, but this should be described in the text. We shouldn't have to read code to understand what they want, even more so because they say their code doesn't work correctly. BTW, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Indeed, that's right. And thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: Thank you all for trying to find a solution, @trincot sorry if my question was so puzzling and maybe I did not offer all the details from the beginning as I should. It is a learning curve for me too :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some code based on my comment (I made some changes to yours too, printing the lines instead of inserting them in the unknown `listbox` object and updating `electric_attributes` with the full name of `batterie`).

```
def count_conditions(input_str):
    electric_attributes = ['electric', 'batterie', "power"]
    input_lines = [line for line in input_str.split('\n') if line]
    open_brackets = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(input_lines):
        if open_brackets == 0:
            # Start of a new outer 'AND' block
            if '{AND' in line:
                open_brackets = line.count('{')
                current_block = line
                block_start = i + 1
                continue
            else: 
                # this shouldn't actually happen! But if it does, ignore the line
                continue
        current_block += line
        if '{' in line:
            open_brackets += line.count('{')
        if '}' in line:
            open_brackets -= line.count('}')
        if open_brackets == 0:   
            # We've reached the end of the current external 'AND' block
            attrs_found = [attr for attr in electric_attributes if attr in current_block]
            if attrs_found:
                l = len(attrs_found)
                print(f'{l} electrical attribute{"s" if l > 1 else ""} found on lines {block_start}-{i + 1}'
                      f' of AND condition: {" ,".join(attrs_found)}')
            else:
                print(f'No electrical attribute found on lines {block_start}-{i + 1}'
                      f' of AND condition')
```

EXAMPLE

```
test='''
{AND
condition_1:batterie
condition_2:samsung
{OR
{AND
condition_1:TV
condition_2:LCD
}
{AND
condition_1:remote
condition_2:TV
}
}
}
{AND
condition_1:batterie
condition_2:samsung
{OR
condition_3:TV
condition_4:remote
}
}
'''

count_conditions(test)
# 1 electrical attribute found on lines 1-14 of AND condition: batterie
# 1 electrical attribute found on lines 15-22 of AND condition: batterie
```

Comment: It's not the 1st time I encounter this problem of embedded data, and I've always found counting the opening/closing "separators" was the simplest way to identify the outer blocks; perhaps it's possible with regex, but then it's beyond my knowledge :)

Comment: I have a week since I'm struggling with regex.. I am not sure it's possible either, thank you so much, I was more than stuck.